# Get x pages based on .all and current objects Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, pagination

I wrote a function that doesn't do what I thought it did, even though the tests were passing.

```
def max_pages(object, current_object, per_page = nil)
  per_page = !per_page.nil? ? per_page : 10
  max_pages = ((object.count - current_object.count )/ per_page.to_f).ceil
end
```

What I am trying to say is, If I give you 10 out of 20 (total) posts and say I want ten posts per page I should get 1 page. **This test works.** But now if I give you 20 posts out of 20 posts and say 10 posts per page, I should get 2 pages. **This test fails**

**Note:** when I say "this test" I mean logic test, not actual rspec.

So to use this function you would do:

```
max_pages(Post.all, post.find(10)) # => 1 pages.

# I should get 2 pages but don't
max_pages(Post.all, Post.all) # => 0 Pages

# This isnt right either, I should only get one page...
max_pages(Post.all, Post.find(5)) # => 2 Pages
```

The last test should only give me one page, because I am only going to display 5 posts out of all the 20 posts, and since I said the default is 10 posts per page, there should be 1 page containing 5 posts.

I think there is a logic issue with:

```
max_pages = ((object.count - current_object.count )/ per_page.to_f).ceil
```

I am not sure what I would change this too.

**The concept, what I want:**

If you have 20 posts and I say I only want 3  posts and that I should show ten posts (by default) per page. I should get one page.

If you have 20 posts and I say I only want 15 posts and that I only allow 5 posts per page I should get 3 pages back.

And finally, If you have 1500 posts and you want only 500 of those, and I only allow 10 posts per page you should have 50 pages.

I could do `(current_object.count/per_page.to_f).ceil` But I understand that you have to take into account how many posts there are in the database.

I could be horribly wrong.

Comment: Your comment doesn't provide any helpful ideas, tips or suggestions. I have clearly laid out what I expect and what I am getting back. Please consider adding some examples or flushing gout your comment. @PrakashMurthy

Comment: @PrakashMurthy is right.  `find(10)` will return the Post whose ID=10; not return the first 10 posts. This is why it's failing.  If you're doing pagination I'd suggest looking at the `will_paginate` or `kamanari` gems.  They handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples, it sounds like you want this:

```
actual_count = [object.count, current_object.count].min
max_pages = (actual_count / per_page.to_f).ceil
```

The only way I can see that the total number of posts is relevant is if you might request more posts than there are in the database, so that's why I put the `min` in there.  If that will never happen, you can remove `object` entirely.  Cleaning up a bit, I'd try this:

```
def max_pages(object, current_object, per_page = 10)
  actual_count = [object.count, current_object.count].min
  (actual_count / per_page.to_f).ceil
end
```